# Add startdate to boostrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date-picker ( https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker )

I need to set start date , below my code , but it seems not working

```
 $('#end_date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            StartDate:"01-08-2020"
  });
```

Comment: are you trying to set a min date value so that the user can't select a date before your example date or are you trying to set the date to a specific one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StartDate Option.
Date or String. Default: Beginning of time
The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled.
Date should be in local timezone. String must be parsable with format.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#startdate

```
$('#end_date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
            language: 'en',
            startDate:"01-08-2020"
  });
```

if you want to use endDate Option that will disable all dates after today.

```
 $('#end_date').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                language: 'en',
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                endDate:"01-08-2020"
  });
```

What's more, you can also use below methods to update or setDate.

```
  $('#end_date').datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');
  $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', '2011-03-05');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Start date option is camel cased
 $('#end_date').datepicker({
       autoclose: true,
       format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
       startDate: "01-08-2020"
  });
```

Documentation is here: (https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)